# Add new dropdown list before more dropdown list Odoo

Tags: odoo

I'm is Odoo new member, I want add new dropdown list before More dropdown list (default in Odoo form)
Can you help me? Thanks you!

Comment: Please show your efforts. What have you tried so far? Edit your question with some code which will be helpful for giving answer.

Comment: Please Go through the odoo documentation first odoo.com/documentation, see there first

Comment: I don't know if adding a new dropdown is possible using the Odoo framework. However, I can guarantee you that it's possible to add customized options to the menu *More*, if it helps you.

Comment: Please add more details to the question